# office add-in doesn't load without enabling cross domain data source access in Internet explorer

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an office-js add-in and In certain windows environments (for example my laptop issued by IT), the add-in does not load without going into internet explorer and changing the security setting: "Access data sources across domains".

What causes this issue only in specific windows environments?

Comment: Do you make any requests to a service from different domain in the code of your add-in?

Comment: Please try investigating with Fiddler, or Visual Studio attach debugger or by running this in the Internet Explore Office online. Look for HTTP 401 or 403s My guess is your corporate policy doesn't allow some cross origin calls originating from add-in. I don't think this is related to accessing OfficeJS CDN or anything like that.